# Difference in compiling with MSBuild and Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild

I'm trying to introduce SonarQube scanning to our code base. I have ASP.NET MVC web application solution. This has roughly 50 projects. The minimum project target framework is .NET 4.5.2 (Some projects are 4.6.2). I can compile this solution absolutely fine in Visual Studio 2015.

I have SonarQube 8.9.3 LTS setup on a development server.

When adding a project on SonarQube the following commands are given to execute (at the solution root) the scanner from your local machine:

Step 1:

```
SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe begin /k:"MyBiz" /d:sonar.host.url="http://devserver:9600" /d:sonar.login="<token>"
```

Step 2:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" MyBiz.sln /t:Rebuild
```

Step 3:

```
SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe end /d:sonar.login="<token>"
```

My problem is that I get an error on step 2 during the build process:

```
"C:\trunk\Dev4.0\MyBiz\MyBiz.sln" (Rebuild target) (1) ->
"C:\trunk\Dev4.0\Common\src\DataLayer\DataLayer.csproj" (Rebuild target) (4) ->
(CopyFilesToOutputDirectory target) ->
  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3813,5): error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "obj\Debug\ILRetail.eBusiness.Common.DataLayer.dll" because it was not found. [C:\trunk\Dev4.0\Common\src\DataLayer\DataLayer.csproj]
```

Obviously this solution compiles fine in Visual Studio so I'm guessing I'm missing some additional parameters on the MSBuild step in this process.

I'm attempted to explicitly use Configuration and Platform properties:

```
/property:Configuration=Debug /property:Platform="AnyCPU"
```

But this did not work:

```
The specified solution configuration "Debug|AnyCPU" is invalid
```

Is there something obvious I'm missing in the build command that would be the reason this works fine in Visual studio but not from command line?

Note in visual studio I would ordinarily compile using Debug & Mixed Platforms. I've attempted to  use these parameters and I still get the same error as supplying no configuration/platform parameter.

Comment: Look at platform on following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/csc-task?force_isolation=true&view=vs-2022

Comment: This question is not SonarQube related. Step 2 is all about the usage of MSBuild.

Comment: @JeroenHeier You're correct I've edited this.